# 'help-echo in font-lock-add-keywords?

Tags: elisp

Is it possible to specify a value for help-echo in the arguments passed to font-lock-add-keywords?

If not, is there an efficient and reliable place to add this property via Font Lock's normal operation?

I've read through "Search-Based Fontification" and "Customizing Keywords" in the elisp manual, and I'm implementing a minor mode by adapting fic-mode.el .

Thanks.

Comment: In general, no. Font-lock is only designed to set the `'face` property.

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll look at "clickable text" instead then.

Comment: @Stefan answered your question.  To be explicit, use `help-echo` as `<prop1>` in his description, giving the help string you want as `<val1>`.  E.g., `'(face font-lock-comment-face help-echo "HELLO THERE")`. If this does what you want then you should accept @Stefan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

While font-lock was designed to manage the `face` property, it can also set any other property.  To set a given property, just use `(face <face> <prop1> <val1> <prop2> <val2> ...)` as the face to apply (if you don't want to apply any face at all, use `nil` for `<face>`).  In order to make it work reliably, you also need to tell font-lock that it manages those extra properties by adding `<prop1>`, `<prop2>` etc to `font-lock-extra-managed-props`.  If you don't, those properties will not be correctly removed when they do not apply any more.